# Line breaks not showing up in multiline column when printing

Tags: list

I have a SharePoint list that has a column that is multi-line and Enhanced Rich Text. However, when I try to print from the list it strips out all of the line breaks and runs all the text together. Is there a way to force the line breaks? When I view the text in the list the line breaks are there as well as when I export it to Excel.
Thank you!